# Change input method of "Description field" in "File" type

Tags: entities

I have added a "File" field in a Content type. Now I can mark the option " Enable Description field". This "Description field" only let use direct input. I need to change this to a select field. I'm not expert in hooks use. I'd like to set it as a dropdown or autocomplete. Which is the best option? create a taxonomy list or a hand made term list? I have to use only in one content type. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it without coding might be to create custom entities with [Entity Construction Kit](https://www.drupal.org/project/eck) and insert them to your content type using [Inline Entity Form](https://www.drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form). Using ECK, you can add the dropdown/autocomplete field and the file field.

You may then need to use something like Automatic Entity Label to prevent the user from needing to enter description/title themselves (The site won't allow me to insert a third URL here, but an internet search for "automatic entity label drupal module" will bring it up).